# TYPO3: Use imageorient properly

Tags: typo3, fluid-styled-content

Running T3 7.6.15

I'd like to use the dropdown field "position" of the textmedia content elements. Adding an item works so far.

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.imageorient.addItems.100 = test
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found out how to use it correctly that it allows me to ask conditions in the fluid template.

The default fluid template uses `position.horizontal` and `position.vertical` as conditions to render the content element accordingly.
When I add an item to the `imageorient`, `position.horizontal` and `position.vertical` are both just empty.

I need to leave the default positions ('above, center', 'above, right',...) untouched because they will be needed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Ah got it!

Instead of `gallery.position.*` use `data.imageorient`.

Then it's quite easy to set the condition

```
<f:if condition="{data.imageorient} == 100">
```

Comment: Exactly. gallery.position.xxx.yyy are derived dynamically from imageorient. So if you add a custom imageorient setting, they will stay empty because there are no defined rules.